# How to remove the blue border after selecting on a chosen selectbox jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found this jquery plugin for selectbox and im using it. I want to remove the blue border-color of the selectbox after finishing select.

Here is an example of the selectbox that shows blue border-color after selecting.

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

tried code:

```
.chosen-select,
.chosen-select:finish,
.chosen-select:focus,
.chosen-select:active,
.chosen-select:hover
 {
 border-color: #ccc;  
  box-shadow:  #ccc;
    outline:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.chosen-container-active .chosen-single {
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #FFF inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select:focus {
    outline-color: #ccc
}
```